# Unterschied zwischen auftreten und eintreten

Tags: meaning

Ich habe *auftreten* nachgeschlagen. Das betont *auftauchen/ erscheinen*.

Aber was betont *eintreten*? Im Folgenden 1. oder 2.?

1. auftauchen/ erscheinen
2. passieren/ geschehen

Comment: Note that "eintreten" has a [lot more](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eintreten) meanings.

Comment: Close voters please take note that the other question is in English, so that we technically not consider it a duplicate.

Comment: Da ich Englisch nur sehr unvollkommen beherrsche, ist mir die intendierte Bedeutung von 'betonen/betont' in der Fragestellung nicht klar. Dass es sich insgesamt um die Frage nach einem Bedeutungs- und/oder Gebrauchsunterschied handelt, kann ich mir allerdings denken.

Answer (score 4):

Alle diese Verben sind sehr ähnlich.

*Eintreten* können nur erwartete Dinge. Dinge, die man nicht erwartet hat, *treten auf*. Dies deckt sich dann auch mit dem Gebrauch des bestimmten Artikels:

> Der Notfall trat ein.
>
> Ein Fehler trat auf.

Comment: Grade "der Notfall" ist doch eher unerwartet, oder?

Comment: @tofro Naja, unerwartete Gäste *betreten*, aber *treten* Sie *herein*? Doch der *Auftritt* einer Band wird in aller Regel mit Spannung erwartet. Die Beispiele zeigen mit "Fehlerfall" und "Notfall", eine semantische Nähe. Ob ein einfacher "Fall" *auf-* oder *eintritt*, kann so nur schwer unterschieden werden und die hier nahegelgte Abgrenzung, die mir auch zuerst in den Sinn kam, wird regelmäßig nicht nachzuweisen sein. Eigentlich, wenngleich etwas absurd, müsste ein "Fall" *fallen*. Daher *fallen* auffällige Fehler hoffentlich *auf*. Vgl. "Vorfall", "Ernstfall", "Unfall", dagegen "Einfall".

Comment: Nein, der *Notfall* ist ein erwarteter Fall. Es ist der Fall, der Not auslöst. Dafür plant man.

Answer (score 3):

Die kürzeste Antwort wäre

> *eintreten* = Wirklichkeit werden
>
> *auftreten* = vorkommen

Aber weder tritt alles ein, was Wirklichkeit wird, noch tritt alles auf, das vorkommt. So kann etwa ein ***Unfall*** weder ein- noch auftreten.

Beide Verben können soweit ich sehe in vielen Fällen durch 'es kommt / kam zu' paraphrasiert werden.

Janka hatte den Gebrauch bereits eingegrenzt. Beide Verben beziehen sich auf Vorkommnisse, die prinzipiell möglich sind, aber in der berichteten Form in der Vergangenheit nicht realisiert bzw. konkretisiert wurden. Anders gesagt: Es geht in beiden Fällen um etwas Neues. Noch etwas präziser könnte man sagen:

> Das Verb **eintreten** bezieht sich auf ein Geschehen, **mit dessen Sich-Ereignen man** mit einer mehr oder weniger großen Wahrscheinlichkeit **gerechnet hatte**. Es können Ereignisse sein, die man sich herbeigewünscht oder befürchtet hatte.
>
> Das Verb **auftreten** bezieht sich auf Vorkommnisse, **die man** bis zum Zeitpunkt der Äußerung **noch nicht beobachtet hatte**.

Beispiele für eintreten:

- *Typisches Beispiel*: Der (genannte) Fall ist jetzt eingetreten.
- Der Tod trat um 3.14 Uhr ein.
- Er hoffte, dass sich seine Begeisterung auf die Gruppe übertragen würde, aber das Gegenteil trat ein: Die Leute reagierten eingeschüchtert.
- Nach wochenlanger intensiver Betreuung und Pflege trat endlich eine Besserung ein.
- Diese Katastrophe ist bereits eingetreten.
- Es trat ein, was sie vorausgesehen hatte.

Beispiele für auftreten:

- *Typisches Beispiel*: Es sind neue Fälle von Ebola aufgetreten.
- Bei diesem Medikament können Nebenwirkungen auftreten, die den Erfolg der Behandlung zunichte machen.
- Ein weiteres Problem trat auf, als die Anlage in Betrieb genommen wurde.
- Wenn nach der Neuinstallation eines Programms ein Fehler auftritt, stellt man am besten den Zustand vor der Installation wieder her.

Beide Verben kommen häufig in Verbindung mit unerwünschten Folgen einer Entwicklung vor.

Noch ein Hinweis: Als mittlerweile beste Möglichkeit, sich in solchen Fragen online zu informieren, betrachte ich *dwds.de*. In diesem Fall geht es bei *eintreten* um die Bedeutungen 2. c) und d), zum Teil überlagert von der Bedeutung 2. b). Bei *auftreten* kommt die Bedeutung 2. c) in Frage. Besonders hilfreich sind jeweils die 'Wortprofile' der gesuchten Wörter, für *eintreten* z.B. unter [DWDS Wortprofil für 'eintreten'](https://www.dwds.de/wp?q=eintreten&comp-method=diff&comp=&minstat=0&minfreq=5&by=logDice&limit=100&view=table) zu finden, dort insbesondere die 3. Tabelle (hat Akk./Dativ-Objekt) und die 6. Tabelle (hat Subjekt). Man kann dort sogar beide Verben (und allgemein zwei Wörter) direkt miteinander vergleichen [DWDS Wortprofil-Vergleich von 'eintreten' und 'auftreten'](https://www.dwds.de/wp?q=eintreten&comp-method=diff&comp=auftreten&pos=4&minstat=0&minfreq=5&by=logDice&limit=100&view=table) und wird feststellen, dass es zwischen den beiden Verben so gut wie keine Überlappungen im Gebrauch gibt. Es werden dort jedoch die Verben in allen vorkommenden Bedeutungen verglichen und nicht nur in den hier anvisierten.